# Test get request in javascript

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I have the next get request:

```js
const getReq = () => {
  fetch(
    'https://api.github.com/repos/javascript-tutorial/en.javascript.info/commits',
  )
    .then((response) => {
      let status = null;
      if (response.status === 200) {
        status = response.status;
      } else {
        status = 'error';
      }
      if (status === 200) {
          alert('success')
      } else {
          alert('Error')
      }
      return response.json();
    })
    .then((commits) =>{
        return commits.map(i=> i.sha[0])
    });
};
getReq()
```

I want to make 3 tests for this request:

1. if I get the first `sha` from commits: `i=> i.sha[0]`
2. check for the 200 response
3. check for the response that is not 200.

I wrote my first test:

```
import { getReq } from './getReq';

global.fetch = jest.fn(() => {
  return Promise.resolve(123);
});
```

```js
describe('success', () => {
  test('get first sha http', async () => {
    const sha = await getReq();
    expect(sha).toBe(123);
  });
});
```

But I get `TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined`.

How to solve the issue with the test above?

Comment: Why do you immediately call `getReq` after defining it? That means it's called on import, *before* you replace `global.fetch`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe, how it should be?

Comment: Have you tried *not* calling `getReq` immediately after defining it?

Comment: @jonrsharpe, how to do this?

Comment: How to not call a function? It's hard to express that in any different way: don't call it.

Comment: @jonrsharpe, but what to put insetead of `expect(sha)`? So what should be instead of `sha`?\

Comment: Not in the _test_, in the _implementation_. Of course you have to call it in the test, otherwise what's the point of the test? But you don't have to (and probably don't want to) immediately call it straight after you define it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225209/discussion-between-asking-and-jonrsharpe).

Comment: @jonrsharpe, i opened a chat, could you get in the chat?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64864737/did-i-properly-mock-the-api-call

Take a look at the above link. I made an working test might be helpful in Your case :)

Answer (score -1):

Your promise is not getting mock.
You can try to adding this on the top of the file.

```
jest.mock(path_of_getReq_file, () => ({
  getReq: jest.fn()
}));
```

Comment: i get `Error: expect(received).toEqual(expected) // deep equality`  , Expected: 123
Received: undefined