# Check if a function was called in testing mode

Tags: javascript

I have this javascript code that make a get request. It works fine.

```js
export const getReq = () => {
  fetch(
    'https://api.github.com/repos/javascript-tutorial/en.javascript.info/commits',
  )
    .then((response) => {
      let status = null;
      if (response.status === 200) {
        status = response.status;
      } else {
        status = 'error';
      }
      if (status === 200) {
        alert('success');
      } else {
        alert('Error');
      }
      return response.json();
    })
    .then((commits) => {
      return commits.map(({sha}) => sha)[0];
    });
};
```

I want to test if my function that fetch was called:

```js
import { getReq } from './getReq';

jest.mock('./getReq', () => ({
    getReq: () => 123
}));

describe('success', () => {
  test('check if was caled', async () => {
    const sha = await getReq();
     expect(sha).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

Doing this test i get the next error:
`Matcher error: received value must be a mock or spy function`
How to test if my function that make a `get` request was called?

Comment: @DigitalDrifter, i use `jest.mock('./getReq', () => ({
    getReq: () => 123
}));`

Comment: Wait, `() => 123` is not a mock right. You need something like `getReq: jest.fn().mockReturnValue(123)`

Comment: @YuryTarabanko, it works, but if now i want to test `expect(sha).toEqual(123)`, i get  `Expected: 123
Received: undefined`. Why? and how to solve it?

Comment: If you want to test that `getReq` calls `fetch`, you need to mock `fetch`, not `getReq`. And you'll `expect(fetch).toHaveBeenCalled()`, not the result of `getReq` (which isn't even a function, as the error says).

Comment: In general it is unclear what you are trying to test. Why do you need to test the result of a mock. Or the fact that function you have just called was actually called. Other commenters are likely right you need to mock `fetch` not `getReq`

Comment: @YuryTarabanko, i need to test if my fetch function haveBeenCaled and if i get dataa from the http request. Could you help?

Comment: You *don't* expect `sha` to have been called, that doesn't make any sense. `sha` is the value returned from `getReq`; you expect it to be `123`. But you've mocked out the whole of `getReq` so **nothing is being tested**; that's the value the *mock* returns.

Comment: This is getting even more unclear. " i need to test if my fetch function haveBeenCaled" you mean you want to test that `getReq` is calling `fetch`? If yes you need to mock `fetch` but call original `getReq`. The second part "and if i get dataa from the http request" is even stranger is this an integration test on github public API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your test, it's not entirely clear whether you know what `getReq` is supposed to do. You mock it out* to return `123`, but assuming the implementation is mostly correct it would actually return a promise of an array of strings where each string is the first character of a `sha` (actually it returns undefined, because you don't return the promise chain, and maybe you actually wanted it to return the complete `sha` of the first commit rather than the first character of the `sha` for every commit?)

Similarly in [your previous attempt](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65037208/3001761) your mock for `fetch` didn't make sense:

```js
global.fetch = jest.fn(() => {
  return Promise.resolve(123);
});
```

Your *code* certainly doesn't expect `fetch` to return a promise of `123`, it expects it to return a promise of a response object with a `status` prop and a `json` method that returns a promise of an array of objects with `sha` props. Your test doubles need to have the same interface as the thing they're replacing, or they're pointless.

Broadly, I would expect a test for this function to look like:

```js
import { getReq } from "./getReq";

it("works", async () => {
  global.alert = jest.fn();  // otherwise 'Error: Not implemented: window.alert'
  global.fetch = jest.fn().mockResolvedValueOnce({
    json: () => Promise.resolve([
      /* from https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/commits/#list-commits */
      { sha: "6dcb09b5b57875f334f61aebed695e2e4193db5e" },
      { sha: "f103561f390825e76f196ce952a982542861fef3" },
    ]),
    status: 200
  });

  const result = await getReq();

  expect(global.alert).toHaveBeenCalledWith("success");
  expect(global.fetch).toHaveBeenCalledWith(
    "https://api.github.com/repos/javascript-tutorial/en.javascript.info/commits"
  );
  expect(result).toEqual(["6", "f"]); // or maybe "6dcb09b5b57875f334f61aebed695e2e4193db5e"?
});
```

This will currently fail on the last expectation for the reason I hint at above.

Alternatively you could split that up into three tests: makes the right request, sends the right alert, returns the right result. There should also be tests for the unhappy paths, e.g. if the request returns non-200 (should you still be assuming the `response.json()` will be fine in that case?)

You could also look into [MSW](https://mswjs.io/) for an approach to testing that's less tightly coupled to the `fetch` API (we shouldn't really be mocking what we don't own).

* *Your test is of a mock, there's no production code involved. **Don't** mock the thing you're supposed to be testing.*

Comment: if do you mean that i need a test for the case when i get not 200 http code status, then yes, i need also a test for this situation. Thanks in advance

Comment: @Asking yes; you should probably have tests for both 1. the request succeeding but with a non-200 status (what's the body in this case?) and 2. the request failing entirely.

Comment: do you mean, what should be in the response besides status in case of non 200?

Comment: also with `expect(result).toEqual("6dcb09b5b57875f334f61aebed695e2e4193db5e"); `, i get Expected: "6dcb09b5b57875f334f61aebed695e2e4193db5e"
Received: undefined

Comment: 1. Yes, what does the JSON method return if the request isn't OK? If it's not in the docs, try making some requests and find out. 2. Yes, because your code doesn't work, I mentioned this in the answer. Use the test to help you fix it.

Comment: 1. For non 200 there should be a message `no data`, and code: `401` for example  2. What do you mean when you say that my code does not work? It works

Comment: @Asking it's unclear whether you mean the function should return that message or it's what you get from GitHub. Either way, I've shown you the test structure and you can fill in the details. And no, it doesn't, as the test is telling you, because it's a promise of undefined, but I'm not going to tutor you through the whole process; again you've got a test structure now, use that to explore what's happening.

Comment: @Asking actually not a promise, sorry, it's not async so it just returns undefined.